# Flake8 plugins installation

Tags: python, lint

I'm using VS code and want to install plugins for flake8.

For example, I installed `flake8-single-quotes` with pip but I can't make it work. `.flake8`:

```
[flake8:local-plugins]
extension =
  MC1 = flake8-single-quotes:SingleQuotes
```

After adding this config, linting doesn't work at all.

Comment: When I execute flake8 --version I get `entrypoints.BadEntryPoint: Couldn't parse entry point spec: u'flake8-single-quotes:SingleQuotes'`